# Css not showing on woocommerce checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i have a checkout page which is not displayed properly (css is not showing),when it is selected under `woo-commerce settings->pages->checkout page`  but it is displayed nicely when not selected in woo-commerce pages.
Any idea how to resolve this issue?
this is the link 
https://phone-phix.com/checkout/

Comment: We have to register in a website to answer your question! Please, provide information to test it.

Comment: @Chexpirit is a live site, cannot provide login info. sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see you call the next CSS file when it is working (example: https://phone-phix.com/shop/)

http://phone-phix.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=3.5.3

But in my account section you are in a different folder, thus is calling the wrong file that is not fetched. (Example: https://phone-phix.com/my-account/)

https://phone-phix.com/sfs/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=3.5.3